# Can I have common namespaces in new rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, project-structure

Is it possible to create whole rails applications under a common namespace?

Lets assume that my company name is Acme, Inc. and I have the following rails projects: Blog, Store, WebService.

By default, if I do something like `rails new blog` the generated applications will be like:

```
module Blog
  class Application < Rails::Application

module Store
  class Application < Rails::Application

module WebService
  class Application < Rails::Application
```

where every project/application is self contained and there is no implicit reference to the company. Ideally I would like to have all this applications under the company namespace, so we can refer to them as:

```
AcmeInc::Blog::Application
  AcmeInc::Blog::Entities::Article

AcmeInc::Store::Application
  AcmeInc::Store::Entities::Product
  AcmeInc::Store::Entities::Order
  AcmeInc::Store::Entities::Customer

etc...
```

Is this possible? Recommended?

---

Using:
ruby-2.0.0-p451, rails 3.2.17

---

Update

Snapshot of generated files and project structure after doing rails new acme/blog as suggested:

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Then how you can call that class methods and where you to include that module?

Comment: Those 3 applications should be independent from each other. Class methods and modules should be called in the same way they are called on the default app. Including AcmeInc is only to group all these apps under the company's codebase identifier. This is very common procedure on .net world, but I am not sure if  ruby/rails apps should follow the same pattern, hence my question.

Comment: What purpose does that grouping serve? If you're trying to have self-contained applications that share some elements and interact, you may want to look at [Rails engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). If your concern is just the namespace for cosmetic purposes, I think you may be fighting some conventions there.

Comment: @tirdadc Most of my projects (at least for the last ~10 yrs) were Microsoft-.Net applications, and I believe it is an extended practice to namespace code like I mentioned. It goes a little bit beyond cosmetic, but it's not necessarily a requirement. My question is open to recommendations on whether should I follow my old practices and conventions or just adapt (no problem!) to the RoR ways.

Comment: @tirdac I believe you were the first to answer my question ("Is this possible? Recommended?") by suggesting use of engines, and to give up the concept of namespaces I was trying to import from .Net to RoR. If you make your comment an answer, I would gladly pick it as the solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with engines.  Each engine is like a standalone app, with it's own routes, test suite, etc, but you can have some common infrastructure like rake tasks, etc.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Answer (score 1):

I think I am probably late here to answer this, as others have already suggested nice approaches. Like, maintaining code within one common repository and creating rails engine.

I would like to share this famous project called spree, which follows the architecture you're looking for. You can visit spree's [code on github here](https://github.com/spree/spree).

For example:

- `Spree::Core` - **spree_core** engine as a gem to maintain all models and base modules etc.
- `Spree::Backend` - **spree_backend** engine as a gem to maintain all admin related controllers, views, assets etc.
- `Spree::Frontend` - **spree_frontend** engine as a gem to maintain user facing code i.e. controllers, views, assets related to it.

I guess you can use it as a reference for your application development.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Spree. I am forking the code to use it as a reference for a project.

Comment: Sure, I'll also encourage you to look into rails code base. It'll help you understand the framework architecture and hacks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to manage your code, why don't you just make a Blog Gem that you can include in each application.  Then you would manage the code under one common repository for the Gem.  Sees to me that's the Rails/Ruby way to do this